# How do I display whole number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, math, product

Let's say I write this in JS:

```
var product = 50000000*39048902222211111111111111111111:
alert(product); //this gives me 1.9524451111105555e+39.
```

Is there any way to display the whole number, and not that *e+39* thing?

Comment: With numbers that big, you need some extra library. Native numbers in JS have to be smaller - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/307179/1169798)

Comment: @Sirko Indeed. you can't print the whole number as javascript doesn't store the whole number. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: That value is larger than the [maximum integer precision](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5) that Javascript can handle. To perform such large integer math and maintain precision you will need to use a library like [`bignumber.js`](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer values you are trying to represent are larger than the integer precision that Javascript can handle (fixed-precision arithmetic). Maximum safe integers are `-9007199254740991` to `9007199254740991` or `+/-(2^53-1)`

While `9007199254740992` can be represented it is considered unsafe. Why? Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/frYs7/)

Javascript

```
alert(9007199254740992 + 1);
```

Output

```
9007199254740992
```

See [specification ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)

But you can use a library for [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), or roll your own.

Using one such library, [`bignumber.js`](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js), loaded using [`require.js`](http://requirejs.org/)

Javascript

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        bignumberjs: 'https://raw.github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/master/bignumber.min'
    }
});

require(['bignumberjs'], function (BigNumber) {
    BigNumber.config({
        EXPONENTIAL_AT: 100
    });

    var product = new BigNumber('50000000').times('39048902222211111111111111111111');

    alert(product);

});
```

Output

```
1952445111110555555555555555555550000000
```

On jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
Number.prototype.realValue = function(){
    return this.toString().replace(/^([+-])?(\d+).?(\d*)[eE]([-+]?\d+)$/, function(x, s, n, f, c){
        var l = +c < 0, i = n.length + +c, x = (l ? n : f).length,
        c = ((c = Math.abs(c)) >= x ? c - x + l : 0),
        z = (new Array(c + 1)).join("0"), r = n + f;
        return (s || "") + (l ? r = z + r : r += z).substr(0, i += l ? z.length : 0) + (i < r.length ? "." + r.substr(i) : "");
    });
};
```

Acess the medthod like:

```
var product = 50000000*39048902222211111111111111111111:
alert(product.realValue())
```

Sources:[Javascript display really big numbers rather than displaying xe+n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066793/javascript-display-really-big-numbers-rather-than-displaying-xen#anwser_16067000)

Comment: Sorry, but you have a loss of precision. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/bVj6R/ gives `1952445111110555500000000000000000000000`