# how to double a float value in a inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i get a float value by this code

```
currentvalue=$("#double_your_btc_stake").val();
```

but when i try to write double of the old value

```
currentvalue*=2;$("#double_your_btc_stake").val(currentvalue);
```

but it write to input box

2e-8

what i do wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/62jJM/

Comment: What's in the input when the process starts?

Comment: You do not have a float, you have a string that the browser changes to a number when you multiply. :)

Comment: [Your code should work fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/) You may have left out some important details.

Comment: What is the value in the textbox to start out? IS there other logic, make a example that shows the error. [JSFiddle.net](http://JSFiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/62jJM/

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/LCmjG/1/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#Double").on("click", function () {
        var currentvalue = $("#double_your_btc_stake").val();
        currentvalue *= 2;
        $("#double_your_btc_stake").val(longnumberstring(currentvalue));
    });
});

function longnumberstring(n) {
    var str, str2 = '',
        data = n.toExponential().replace('.', '').split(/e/i);
    str = data[0], mag = Number(data[1]);
    if (mag >= 0 && str.length > mag) {
        mag += 1;
        return str.substring(0, mag) + '.' + str.substring(mag);
    }
    if (mag < 0) {
        while (++mag) str2 += '0';
        return '0.' + str2 + str;
    }
    mag = (mag - str.length) + 1;
    while (mag > str2.length) {
        str2 += '0';
    }
    return str + str2;
}
```

**HTML:-**

```
<input type="text" id="double_your_btc_stake" style="width:500px" />
<input type="button" id="Double" value="Double" />
```

Used <kbd>[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4170969/467853s)</kbd> to convert the exponential to long string.

Comment: @user2061745 Does this answer your question?

Answer (score -2):

Simply use this:

```
parseFloat($("#yourId").val())
```

Comment: This should not be necessary.  The multiplication will implicitly convert the string to a number (if it's a valid number of course).